# Paragraph cuts bottom of image? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, height

I need a little help here. I created a larger button on my order page and the bottom gets cut off to close. I need to add a little space on the bottom. I added a 1px border so you can see how it's laid out. You can view the problem here: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s329/sh/a408b2ff-472c-481a-8fb1-b9e48c1205e1/5ddd92e9d940c78a57487e07d6eedcd4

```
<p><span id="old-price">$199 </span>
    <span id="new-price">$147</span>
    <strong><font color="#FF0000">
    35% off! &quot;Halloween Special&quot; </font></strong><em>Expires Nov 1st.</em>
<p class="cart-btns">
    <a href="https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&i=CAP2S&cl=133613&ejc=2" target="ej_ejc" class="add-to-cart ec_ejc_thkbx" onclick="javascript:return EJEJC_lc(this);"></a>
</p>

    .products li p.cart-btns a.add-to-cart {
width: 120px;
height: 50px;
background: url(images/add-to-cart.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an inline object and will not accept a `height`.  Use `margin: 5px` or put `padding:5px` in the `p.cart-btns {}`

You can also just `float:left` the `a.add-to-cart {}` to make it ignore the boundaries in a way (takes out of the normal flow of the document).

Comment: I tried adding padding and margin but the button disapears. Should I just make the button image inline?

Comment: jeez i didnt even realize you were using a background-image lol add this:  `background-size: cover`

Comment: @Mark don't forget to mark this answer as accepted - gives credit to the answerer and keeps helpful people from spending time viewing this question.